# React Native Flatlist is not re-rendering while update or create?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-native-flatlist

I have been trying to refresh the flatlist after adding the new address but the Flatlist does not update.

Api Call:

```
getProducts = async () => {
    let resp = await this.props.getOutlets();
    console.log("respOOOOOOOOOOOOOO:::", resp)
};
```

Here is the code for constructor:

```
 this.state = {
        ouId,
        outlets: [],
    };
```

Here is the code for the

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.outlet.outlets) {
        return ({ outlets: nextProps.outlet.outlets })
    }
    return null
};
```

Here is the code for Flatlist:

```js
{
  this.state.outlets && (
    <FlatList
      horizontal={false}
      data={this.state.outlets}
      extraData={this.state}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
      renderItem={({ item: outlet }) => {
        return (
          <Card
            gotoOutletDetail={this.gotoOutletDetail}
            ouId={this.state.ouId}
            updateOutlet={this.updateOutlet}
            key={outlet._id}
            outlet={outlet}
          />
        );
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    />
  );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated pls...

Comment: Looks like you are using redux and that `getOutlets` is your action. If that's the case then you need to check your action and make sure it's dispatched correctly. If you are not using redux then your need to use `setState` after getting your response. Also Michael Bahl is right you don't need `getDerivedStateFromProps` Checkout this article: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Why using getDerivedStateFromProps here, I think it‘s not necessary.

In case I am wrong and you really need getDerivedStateFromProps:

Return an array in any case:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    return ({ outlets: nextProps?.outlet?.outlets || []})
};
```

Remove conditional rendering:

```
{
    <FlatList
      horizontal={false}
      data={this.state.outlets}
      extraData={this.state}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
      renderItem={({ item: outlet }) => {
        return (
          <Card
            gotoOutletDetail={this.gotoOutletDetail}
            ouId={this.state.ouId}
            updateOutlet={this.updateOutlet}
            key={outlet._id}
            outlet={outlet}
          />
        );
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    />
}
```

Comment: Still, the flatlist is not updated. When coming back to the view

Comment: updated the code for API and constructor

Comment: In your code it seems you do nothing return of getOutlets except print the log.